# Tkinter, Display Two Images Side-By-Side

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am trying to have two BMP images displayed side by side using Tkinter. Once the second image is opened, the first image should reposition itself to the left, and the second image position itself to the right. When I try to do this, the other image goes missing or is replaced. How would I go about doing this? Also, my screen monitor is 1920 x 1080, so image resizing may vary.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.pos = []
        self.master.title("BMP Image GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        # File Bar
        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Open Image 1", command=self.openImage1)
        file.add_command(label="Open Image 2", command=self.openImage2)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.image = None  
        self.image2 = None  

    #Image 1
    def openImage1(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(),title="Select BMP File",
                                              filetypes=[("BMP Files","*.bmp")])
        if not filename:
            return 
        load = Image.open(filename)
        load = load.resize((960, 720), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        if self.image is None: 
            w, h = load.size
            width, height = root.winfo_screenmmwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
            self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)  
            self.image = self.canvas.create_image((w / 2, h / 2), image=self.render)
            root.geometry("%dx%d" % (w, h))
        else:
            w, h = load.size
            width, height = root.winfo_screenmmwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
            root.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
            self.canvas.move(self.image, 960, 0)
            self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load) 
            self.image2 = self.canvas.create_image((w / 2, h / 2), image=self.render)

    # Image 2
    def openImage2(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Select BMP File",
                                              filetypes=[("BMP Files", "*.bmp")])
        if not filename:
            return 
        load = Image.open(filename)
        load = load.resize((960, 720), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        if self.image is None:  
            w, h = load.size
            self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)  
            self.image = self.canvas.create_image((w / 2, h / 2), image=self.render)
            root.geometry("%dx%d" % (w, h))
        else:
            w, h = load.size
            width, height = root.winfo_screenmmwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
            root.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
            self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)  
            self.image2 = self.canvas.create_image((w / 2, h / 2), image=self.render)
            self.canvas.move(self.image2, 960, 0)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d" % (300, 300))
root.title("BMP Image GUI")
app = Window(root)
app.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using "self.render" for both image objects. So when you make one the other gets garbage collected. Use unique names.

```
self.render1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load) 
self.image1 = self.canvas.create_image((w / 2, h / 2), image=self.render1)
```

Comment: Just got it! Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out! Just had to create a new `render` in my second else statements. Labeled as `render2`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.pos = []
        self.master.title("BMP Image GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        # File Bar
        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Open Image 1", command=self.openImage1)
        file.add_command(label="Open Image 2", command=self.openImage2)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.image = None
        self.image2 = None

    def openImage1(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(),title="Select BMP File",
                                              filetypes=[("BMP Files","*.bmp")])
        if not filename:
            return
        load = Image.open(filename)
        load = load.resize((960, 720), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        if self.image is None:
            w, h = load.size
            width, height = root.winfo_screenmmwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
            self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
            self.image = self.canvas.create_image((w / 2, h / 2), image=self.render)
            root.geometry("%dx%d" % (w, h))
        else:
            w, h = load.size
            width, height = root.winfo_screenmmwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
            root.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
            self.canvas.move(self.image, 960, 0)
            self.render2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
            self.image2 = self.canvas.create_image((w / 2, h / 2), image=self.render2)

    def openImage2(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Select BMP File",
                                              filetypes=[("BMP Files", "*.bmp")])
        if not filename:
            return
        load = Image.open(filename)
        load = load.resize((960, 720), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        if self.image is None:
            w, h = load.size
            self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
            self.image = self.canvas.create_image((w / 2, h / 2), image=self.render)
            root.geometry("%dx%d" % (w, h))
        else:
            w, h = load.size
            width, height = root.winfo_screenmmwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
            root.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
            self.render2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
            self.image2 = self.canvas.create_image((w / 2, h / 2), image=self.render2)
            self.canvas.move(self.image2, 960, 0)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d" % (300, 300))
root.title("BMP Image GUI")
app = Window(root)
app.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
root.mainloop()
```